# Speeding up detection of overlapping time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, datetime

I am working on my thesis about charging of electrical vehicles and I am trying to do a time series plot that shows how many cars are using a charging station through out time. As an example I have created the data below:

```py
base = datetime.datetime(2021,3,2)
start_time = np.array([base + datetime.timedelta(hours=12),
         base + datetime.timedelta(hours=12,minutes=3),
         base + datetime.timedelta(hours=12,minutes=20),
         base + datetime.timedelta(hours=12,minutes=50)])

end_time = np.array([start_time[0] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=25),
                   start_time[1] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=32),
                   start_time[2] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=25),
                     start_time[3] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start_time','end_time'])
df['start_time'] = start_time
df['end_time'] = end_time
df['is_obs'] = 1
```

What I really want to know if for every 5 minutes how many observations are *alive*, so between their start and end time. First I construct the time steps for the intervals:

```py
# create range of datetime objects with 5 min intervals. 
indx = pd.date_range(start=min(df.start_time),end=max(df.end_time), freq='5T')
# convert to numpy array
indx = np.array(indx.to_pydatetime())
# add extra interval at the end so the full spectrum of an observation is within the interval
indx = np.append(indx, (indx[-1] + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5)))
```

Finally, I loop over every time interval and checks if the time span of every observation is within the time interval. To do this I use the package `datetimerange`.

```py
count_obs = np.zeros(len(indx)-1) 
for i in range(0,len(indx)-1): # iterate over time intervals
    time_range = DateTimeRange(indx[i],indx[i+1]) 
    for index, row in df.iterrows(): # iterate over all observations in dataframe
        x = DateTimeRange(row.start_time, row.end_time) 
        if time_range.is_intersection(x):
            count_obs[i] += 1
```

This gives me the results:

```py
array([2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

However, if I try and scale this up for my full dataset where the total time span is around 2 years (and thereby more than 210.000 5-minute time intervals) and with 2000+ observations it takes forever.

Do any of you guys know how I potentially can speed up the process?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to iterate over the time intervals instead of the input data. For your toy example that could look like

```
t0, tmax = df['start_time'].min(), df['end_time'].max()
t1 = t0 + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)
d = {'t0': [], 't1': [], 'nobs': []}

while t0 < tmax:
    # lower boundary included, upper boundary excluded
    m = (df['end_time']>t0) & (df['start_time']<=t1)
    d['t0'].append(t0)
    d['t1'].append(t1)
    d['nobs'].append(m.sum())
    t0, t1 = t1, t1 + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(d)

# df_out
#                     t0                  t1  nobs
# 0  2021-03-02 12:00:00 2021-03-02 12:05:00     2
# 1  2021-03-02 12:05:00 2021-03-02 12:10:00     2
# 2  2021-03-02 12:10:00 2021-03-02 12:15:00     2
# 3  2021-03-02 12:15:00 2021-03-02 12:20:00     3
# 4  2021-03-02 12:20:00 2021-03-02 12:25:00     3
# 5  2021-03-02 12:25:00 2021-03-02 12:30:00     2
# 6  2021-03-02 12:30:00 2021-03-02 12:35:00     2
# 7  2021-03-02 12:35:00 2021-03-02 12:40:00     1
# 8  2021-03-02 12:40:00 2021-03-02 12:45:00     1
# 9  2021-03-02 12:45:00 2021-03-02 12:50:00     1
# 10 2021-03-02 12:50:00 2021-03-02 12:55:00     1
# 11 2021-03-02 12:55:00 2021-03-02 13:00:00     1
# 12 2021-03-02 13:00:00 2021-03-02 13:05:00     1
```